# PhoneGap Kendo UI: adding hidden element doesn't allow to scroll to it

Tags: javascript, cordova, kendo-ui

I'm building an app using kendo ui and phone gap, I want to show elements on button click, it works fine but it doesn't update the view height so I'm not able to scroll to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this by calling the scroller:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
app.scroller();
```

even without doing anything it updates the height of the application and solves the problem